# Filters and subsets.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X\neq\emptyset$ be a set and $A\subset X$ and $A\neq\emptyset$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be filter on $X$.

“$\mathcal{F}\cap A=\{F\cap A: F\in\mathcal{F}\} \text{ is a filter on } A \text{ iff } F\cap A\neq\emptyset \text{ for each} F\in\mathcal{F}$.

It is not hard to show that from left to right. Let $F\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for each $F\in\mathcal{F}$. Then $\emptyset\notin\mathcal{F}\cap A$.

If $F_{1}\cap A,  F_{2}\cap A\in\mathcal{F}\cap A$, since $F_{1}\cap F_{2}\in\mathcal{F}$, then $(F_{1}\cap F_{2})\cap A\in\mathcal{F}\cap A$

But how can I show that, for every $F\cap A\in\mathcal{F}\cap A$ and $F\cap A\subset U$, then $U\in\mathcal{F}\cap A$? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You need to prove: if $F\cap A\in\mathcal{F}\cap A$ and $F\cap A\subset U \subset A$, then $U\in\mathcal{F}\cap A$.

Comment: Maybe you can also use contraposition.

Comment: So how can I use it? Really, I could not forward. @smth

Comment: If $(F\cap A)\subset U$, where $U\in\mathscr{P}(A)$, just put $G=F\cup U$; then $G\in\mathcal{F}$ and $U=(G\cap A)\in\mathcal{F}\cap A$.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much for this illuminating answer. @jpboucheron

Comment: You're welcome.